# Visual Studio Code SFTP plugin. Reload all opened files

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am learning VS Code for PHP coding.
I usually edit PHP file directly on my server with ssh access (SFTP).
I gfigured out how to open files on SFTP server and save them.

But i also need a way to reload all opened files.

When i change git branch on my server i need to reload all opened file (all files in a local copy?) to be sure i have actual view after a branch change.

I see how i can refresh single file (right click menu and Download). How can i refresh all files? To do Download of all files? Or reset local copy of all files or refresh them?

I use the SFTP plugin by liximono

Answer (score 0):

Go to the VSCode Explorer where you have the local files and you can select multiple files to download.

You can also download folders but be aware that it will download the folder recursively. This means all its files and not only the files you currently have locally.